# Silverlight 4 get a reference to the control inside a IValueConverter

Tags: silverlight, binding, silverlight-4.0

The title basically says it for me... I need to be able to get a reference to a control inside my `IValueConverter` implementation. I have seen plenty of posts around `MultiBinding`, which Silverlight doesnt have.

Can I use the `ConverterParameter` somehow to get a reference to its self?